# How to add a button to viewpager with setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, button, android-viewpager

I have a layout with a buttons. I use FragmentActivity:

```
public class slidepage extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

private ViewPager mPager;

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);


    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    Button Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

    Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onBackPressed();

        }
    });

}

}
```

slide class:

```
public class slider extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup view;

    if(GlobalConfig.tryb) {
        view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.n_podglad, container, false);
    } else {
        view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.d_podglad, container, false);
    }

    /* Powrót */

    Button Back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.back);

    Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //onBackPressed();

        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Unfortunately my button not works. I receive null reference in log. What is wrong? How can I set OnClickListener on my buttons in viewpager?

Comment: You should findviewById in ScreenSlidePagerAdapter.

Comment: Show you xml layout and ScreenSlidePagerAdapter code.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` in `instantiateItem` method write your button click not in your `slidepage`

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_layout, null);
    Button Back= (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.back);
    Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        onBackPressed();

    }
  });
    return layout;
}
```

Comment: are you sure? When I added public Object then it's a marked on red. I added Button Back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.back); "view.*" now it is works. How can I pass getCurrentItem? I want create method onBackPressed(); and set condition with setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);

Comment: has the above answer solved button click inside `viewpager`. also can you please update your question it is not clear.